# Chapel programming language. Work with database

Tags: database, parallel-processing, chapel

Could you please, help me in follow question: how I can work with database from my Chapel programm?

Thanks

Comment: Ch 31 of (the latest revision of) the Chapel Language Specification covers interoperability with, in particular, C.  I guess that if your database exposes a C (or C-like) API you should be able to access it from your Chapel programs.

Comment: Thank you! Using this I can to work with my data. My data are in MySQL database and I have experience with MySQL through C. I see that 31.2.3 have information about this.

Answer (score 5):

Just an update. The comment by High Performance Mark on the question did a great job of answering the question. I wanted to provide a link to some more current documentation.

Have a look at [C Interoperability](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/latest/technotes/extern.html) which describes the options for calling C libraries. Note that Chapel supports a way to call C code directly (without explicitly using the foreign function interface) with the extern block feature.

```
extern {
   #include <stdio.h>
   static void hello(void) {
     printf("Hello Chapel and C Interoperability!\n");
   }
}

hello();
```

There's quite a lot more you can do - see  the C Interoperability document linked above for details.

Another interesting option for working with libraries is [the Python/Chapel integration module](http://pychapel.readthedocs.io/).

Answer (score 1):

There is now the [CDO Library](https://github.com/marcoscleison/cdo) which I use extensively to connect to Postgres.  Works great!